# Unable to manually bind driver in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers

Basically I'm trying to bind a test USB driver that is on [github](https://github.com/agelastic/eudyptula/tree/master/task5). It is basically just a very simple USB driver if you want to test it for yourself.

Here are the steps I did:

- Use `lsusb -t` to find what bus and port my usb was connected on. I found out that it was `1-3`.
- Went to `/sys/bus/usb/devices` and found `1-3` there, and found that it was bound to `drivers/usb`.
- Used `echo 1-3 > unbind` to unbind it. I was able to successfully unbind it.
- Went to the `devices` folder and checked if `1-3` was still bound to anything. It was not.
- Went to the directory of my own driver, named `hello_driver`
- Tried to do `echo 1-3 > bind` but I get the error message `echo: write error: No such device`

Here is the output of `lsusb -t` if it is helpful.

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. I know other people have asked this but their solutions didn't help in my case. It seems as if this error only appears in my own driver, but not others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the exact same problem. In my case, the issue was that the USB device needs to be registered in the driver code using the product and vendor id:

```
const struct usb_device_id etx_usb_table[] = {
    {USB_DEVICE(USB_PRODUCT_ID, USB_VENDOR_ID)},
    {}
};
;

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, etx_usb_table);
```

I guess that's where the error "No such device" originates from. The device is looked up globally and not found.

Comment: Maybe the OP will find this to be perfectly clear and complete. But it would be a better answer by [SE] standards if you added a few words to describe *how* somebody in the OP’s position would use this information. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.